# Google Analytics for Mac OSx application

Tags: objective-c, analytics

Is it possible to use Google Analytics API's to track Mac OSX applications?
If not could any one suggest me an alternative for Google Analytics.

Comment: I've used [Google's mobile SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html) in my iOS apps, perhaps worth considering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Analytics is designed to work with web applications not for desktop apps. Although it might be possible to collect info about your application and send it to your Google Analytic account but the amount of work required to retrofit might be better spent, building your own Analytic solution.

A good starting point would be to create a simple web service, which collects information regarding clicks. Then rewrite your application to call that web service on every click within your application.

You would ideally want to store this information locally and submit it to the web service in batches. You would also want to design the application, so that if you ever shut down the web service, the application would still be able to operate.

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments by Václav Slavík, they have added apps analytics for iOS/Android.

Comment: Not true, they do have apps analytics for iOS/Android now.

Answer (score 4):

I made a simple set of classes for doing this:

https://github.com/stephenlind/SimpleCocoaGoogleAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is not only for web applications, but also for mobile. It's available on the platform like  android, iOS, etc. If you want to track your MAC OS X application, you can choose DeskAppTrack or DeskMetrics. DeskAppTrack is only available on MAC. It provide a professional data statistical analysis and it's free. While DeskMetrics is available on MAC and Windows. Either one is ok.

Comment: DeskAppTrack is no longer available!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how detailed you want to get.  If you are are truly looking for analytics with detail and control flow data, you are better suited to created your own web service, as mentioned.

However, if you simply want to know a small number of operations, that occur at a small volume, i.e. when the app is launched (a quick and dirty solution): then in theory you could create a landing page on your site that contains a minimal head section, and a blank body, and then load the URL with an NSURL when you want to trigger the action.

Of course, you would have to include the google analytics tracking codes in the header, and you may need to load an off-screen webview to get the javascript to run.  Like I said, quick and dirty.

In either case, you want to make sure the application will continue to perform properly, even if the web service / page is not present.